# QTextStream fixed point formatting issue

Tags: qt, formatting, qtextstream

I'm having an issue with the QTextStream formatting. I'm using the code below to print a percentage from a quint8 and it seems to be giving me a space in between the number and the decimal point. For example, I'll get "50 %" instead of "50%" and "100 %" instead of "100%".

What's my problem?

```
QString retVal;
QTextStream retStream(&retVal);
retStream.setRealNumberNotation(QTextStream::FixedNotation);
retStream.setRealNumberPrecision(0);
retStream << qSetFieldWidth(2)
          << (100*((float)myQuint8)/255.0) << "%";
return retVal;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`QTextStream::setFieldWidth` documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html#setFieldWidth)

> **Note**: The field width applies to every element appended to this stream after this function has been called (e.g., it also pads endl).
>   This behavior is different from similar classes in the STL, where the
>   field width only applies to the next element.

So you need to reset the field width to zero before you output the '%' character.

Comment: Ahhh. When I read that, I thought it meant every element collectively. Now it makes sense.  That's a strange and annoying behavior though...